# Raspberry Pi Zero no data over SCP at low data transmission

Tags: scp, openssh, data-transfer, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Zero connected to a SIM7600G-H 4G HAT with a camera module connected. I want to use it as a webcam, who makes a picture in a defined cycle and send's it via scp to a web server who display it on a homepage.The created shell script is started via a CRONJob every 2 hours.

The whole setup works very well if I have a good, powerful SIM connection. However, as soon as I operate the setup at the desired location, a strange behavior appears.

At the location where I run the webcam I only have a relatively poor 3G connection, if I run the scp command from a connected laptop it works fine. I can therefore assume that the problem has nothing to do with the SIM module.

The Raspian shows two peculiar behaviors.

1. Even though i created a key and gave it to the webserver, every now and then it wants me to enter the password when i run the scp command.This does not happen when I connect directly to the webserver via ssh.
2. The first few images the raspian loads without problems using scp command on the webserver, but then suddenly it does not work anymore.

I send two pictures each. I replace one with an existing one on the web server. This is the image that is displayed on the homepage and another one I put in an archive folder named after the timestamp. It looks like this:

```
scp foo.jpg <username>@webserver:dir/to/folder/default.jpg
FILENAME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
scp foo.jpg <username>@webserver:dir/to/archive_folder/${FILENAME}.jpg
```

Because of the password issue I downloaded an additional service called sshpass and added in addition to the scp command the following command:

```
sshpass -p <password>
```

However, it seems like the issue is not related to sshpass since it also happens if I try it only with the scp command and enter the password by my self.

At the end for the "new file" which goes into the archive folder, the raspian creates the filename at the web server, but he does not transmit the data of the file. At the end, the file remains empty.
The file which should be replaced "default.jpg" is not touched at all.

I tried to find out what happens via the debug output. But there is no useful information. It always stops with the line who shows the transmission state and with 0% and 0KB/s.

I have now spent several days on a solution. I have also already taken it home and everything has suddenly worked smoothly again. But as soon as I mounted it there again, the problem reappeared.

Does anyone know of a bug with the raspberry zero that it can no longer transfer scp files when the data transfer rate is low? One image is about 300kb and my laptop takes about 20 seconds to transfer over the same connection as the one from the Raspberry.

Comment: Try posting your question here also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

After countless attempts, my simplest solution was to set up a cronjob, which restarts the raspberry shortly before it takes a photo for the webcam. It then searches for a new network and finds it very reliably.